# Radio button list malfunction

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, vb.net-2010

How can I check if a radio button inside a radio button list is checked?

I used if radiobuttonlist1.selectedindex > -1 and then I checked a radio button, but it is not reading the selected radio button, it is always going to the else statement.

this is my code:

```
Dim rl1 As RadioButtonList = New RadioButtonList()

If rbl1.SelectedIndex > -1

    Label2.Text = "Checked"

Else

    Label2.Text = "Not Checked" 

End If
```

Comment: The c# tag should not be included here, so I decide to removed it.

Comment: Seems like you should have the `Checked` attribute. Have you tried [this](https://www.vbtutor.net/vb2019/vb2019_lesson22.html)?
From the same site you can refer to VB2010 [here](https://www.vbtutor.net/vb2010/vb2010_Lesson18.html)

Comment: I removed the Visual Studio tags as its code related, not environment

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

Go to your **`RadioButton_CheckedChanged`** event and add this code

```
If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
    Me.Label1.Text = "Checked"
Else
    Me.Label1.Text = "UnChecked"
End If
```

Comment: i can not do this i am adding radio buttons dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct variable name in your code? You are declaring rl1 but validating rbl1. If it's not the case, check if the following code helps:

```
    Dim rl1 As RadioButtonList = New RadioButtonList()
    
    'Just adding some items and selecting one of them for demonstration
    rl1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Option 1", "1"))
    rl1.Items.Add(New ListItem("Option 2", "2"))
    rl1.SelectedIndex = 1
    
    If rl1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then

        MsgBox("Checked")

    Else

        MsgBox("Not Checked")

    End If
```

Comment: hi in my code it is rl1 but here i added the b by mistake. but also in my code i added items like this rl1.Items.Add(New ListItem(qdesc, rl1.ID)) the qdesc is a question from the database and the rl1.ID is  rl1.ID = "A". i am looping in the code to populate 4 questions with 1 radio button for each. the problem is when i select a question it is not reading the selected question so the code is always reading the "not checked".

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rl1 As RadioButtonList = New RadioButtonList()
```

So you created the above? How does the above know or have anything to do with the web page? There is zero relationship between some variable you create in code as opposd to the controls you have on the web page?

You want

```
MyRadioButtonOnTheWebPage.Selectedindex
```

Probably this:

RadioButtonList1.Selected index.

So, you would not out of the blue create + dim some variable that has nothing to do with the actual Radio button list on the actual web page. I mean, if you have 3 RadioButton lists on your web page, which one does the above refer to?

So, if you have a Radiobuttion list "1" like this:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Tow</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then either a button postback, or EVEN say set the autopostback = true for the radio button list.

Then in code you can use:

```
    Debug.Print(RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex)
    Debug.Print(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue)
```

So above would get the index value, or the actual value of the radio button.

And if you have auto postback = true, then you can/would use the event (changed) like this that will trigger when you choose/change the selection in the radio button

```
Protected Sub RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Debug.Print(RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex)
    Debug.Print(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue)

End Sub
```

Comment: hi in fact i did not understand what you mean mr.Albert but in my code i have  added 
4 items like this rl1.Items.Add(New ListItem(qdesc, rl1.ID)) i added them using a loop. The qdesc is a question from the database and the rl1.ID ="A"  i am looping in the code to populate 4 questions with 1 radio button for each. the problem is when i select a question it is not reading the selected question so the code is always going to the else statement which contains the "not checked" . to check if radiobutton is selected i have used  If rl1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            Label2.Text = "checked"

Comment: My example don't matter if you loop to add values to a radiobutton list. you have to post more code and more markup. It not clear how you can have say 3 or 10 readio butotns. I assume some kind of repeater is being used here? You have to post the markup, since what I posted works for ONE button list - and it does not matter if you loop to add 2 or 15 choices to the one radio button. What is not AT ALL clear is how you are rendering and have setup the ability to have 2 or 8 or 10 radio buttons on the form. Without that information, we are playing darts with a blindfold and in the dark.